# SharePoint 2013 : how to target the audience of navigation link to "Everyone except external users"?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, audience-targeting, global-navigation

Well, everything is in the title :

I have a  Team Site, and i would like to configure an audience for a link on the Global Navigation. This audience should be "Everyone except external users", a SP group created by O365. (working on SP2013 Online)

Because Sharepoint Server Publication functionnality is not active (and won't be), i pass by a specific URL to set my audiences.
This one : < SiteCollection >/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

So once i'm on this page, i select the link under "Globale navigation" tree and click on "edit".
On that pop-up, i enter the "Tout le monde sauf les utilisateurs externes" (which is the french translation for "Everyone except external users" group) in the input of "audiences". But Sharepoint say there is no such group. I tried with english version, french version, only few words...

I've tried through the pop up "Select audiences" by changing the dropdown between "SharePoint Groups", "global audiences" and "distribution/security groups", but SP did not found my group.

But strangely this group IS present in the SharePoint groups !

Do you have any ideas on how i could achieve this ? Not by code, but only by site settings please?

Thanks a lot.
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work in my tenant either.  A workaround is to create a SharePoint group, add the built-in group to it, and then target the link to the group you created.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your workaround worked like a charm !
Really silly for SharePoint to not make it work.